# Using Javascript to replace HTML in SharePoint page

Tags: javascript, html, regex, sharepoint

I'm trying to replace some HTML tags in a SharePoint page with Javascript. I have the following code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<\s*?TR\s*?><\s*?TD class=\Sms-stylelabel\S>Current Projects/gi, '<TR bgcolor:#D9D9D9><TD class="ms-stylelabel">Current Projects');
```

And it appears to work; however, when I place it in the page, it doesn't. I'm wondering if there is a problem since the Current Projects section goes on a new line and has some odd tabbing/spacing. I can't change this in the SharePoint page itself. Any advice or things to try would be much appreciated!

Comment: A regular expression will allow you to match and replace characters in a string, no elements in a page.

Comment: @Mark you missed the point with the edit, the OP is actually using a regular expression

Comment: That code was all that I could find on the page. Re-edit it if you can find more info.

Comment: It would be great if you could post your javascript code.

Comment: @Mark the regex is the first line on the linked page (so you know for next time). I am voting to close the question as it doesn't make sense and the OP doesn't seem to care much anyway.

Comment: I have edited the question again (if the edit gets accepted) including the regex.

Comment: Sorry it was my first post on here, I've edited to show the code. The first time I pasted it didn't work.

Comment: I'm readding the code link http://refiddle.com/gzv since it may be useful to be able to test the code somewhere if someone is able to assist me. Thanks!

Comment: Where in the page are you inserting your script? If the script is inserted before the page has loaded, there won't be anything in the document's innerHTML for it to replace...

Comment: It's a SharePoint page so I'm not sure when it is being loaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1256925